# Coroutine' object is not callable? Aiogram Telegram Bot

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Кидает ошибку `'TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'on_startup' was never awaited'`
Как я могу написать по-другому проверку забанил ли пользователь бота или нет

```
async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    arr = database.get_all_user_id()
    for user_id in arr:
        try:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id[0], text="Бот запущен!")
        except BotBlocked:
            pass



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup = on_startup(dp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Делай так

```
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```